# Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I've tried several methods to serach a client who have a propritaire.id in membresEquipeDuClient list, but each time I'm getting the "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."-error!

I got the error in the second request,

The methods I've used :

```
List<TeamMembership> membresEquipeDuClient = (from k in context.CreateQuery<TeamMembership>()
                                              where k.teamid == equipeDuClient.Id
                                              select k).ToList();
var pRechercheNumeroClient = (from p in context.CreateQuery<Client>()
                              where membresEquipeDuClient.Any(a => a.systemuserid == p.proprietaire.Id)
                              select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thx for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, `Any` is not supported, but `Contains` is. So you can do:

```
var systemUserIds = 
(
    from k in context.CreateQuery<TeamMembership>()
    where k.teamid == equipeDuClient.Id
    select k.systemuserid // Select the Id only
).ToList();

var pRechercheNumeroClient = 
(
    from p in context.CreateQuery<Client>()
    where systemUserIds.Contains(p.proprietaire.Id)
    select p
).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm not familiar with Dynamics CRM, but I think you can remove the `ToList` from the first statement, so it will be an `IQueryable` and both statements will be executed as one expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pRechercheNumeroClient = (from p in context.CreateQuery<Client>()
                              where membresEquipeDuClient.Select(a => a.systemuserid).Contains(p.proprietaire.Id)
                              select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: LinqToCRM doesn't implement the full range of Linq features as it can only support what CRM Query Expression allows.

.Any() is not supported by the CRM Linq provider but projecting the property first and using .Contains() is.


Some useful information on limitations on the various query mechanisms is here (there may be slight differences between CRM2011 and CRM2013 but nothing fundemental)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2013/01/14/crm-2011-sdk-query-limitations-by-api.aspx